# JQuery Show Div on Hover

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to use JQuery to display some tools when the user is hovering over a content block.  For example, the blocks are displayed as follows with the tools initially hidden:

```
<div id="block_1">
    <div class="tools" style="display:none;">Tools Here</div>
</div>

<div id="block_2">
    <div class="tools" style="display:none;">Tools Here</div>
</div>
```

I need it to show the tools for block_1 when the user is hovering over anything in block_1.

I see that you can use wildcards to do something like:

```
$("*[id^=block_]").hover(
    function () {
        // somehow toggle div.tools for this block
    },
    function () {
       // somehow toggle div.tools for this block
    }
```

I just can't figure out how you can specifically toggle just the div.tools  for that block...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do this:

```
$("*[id^=block_]").hover(
    function() {
        // Styles to show the box
        $(this).children('.tools').css(...);
    },
    function () {
        // Styles to hide the box
        $(this).children('.tools').css(...);
    }
);
```

You may want to consider just using `$.addClass()` and `$.removeClass()`, as it would be much easier to manage.

Answer (score 11):

EDIT: Ultimately, if you're just doing simple style changes, you should use CSS to accomplish this. Not javascript.

This CSS won't work for IE6, but it will for pretty much all other modern browsers.

Give the parent `block_` elements a class like `block`, remove the inline styles from `tools`, then do this:

```
.block .tools {
    display: none;
}
.block:hover .tools {
    display: block;
}
```

---

You could do this:

```
$(function() {
    $("div[id^=block_]").hover( function ( e ) {
        $(this).children('.tools').toggle(e.type === 'mouseenter');
    });
});
```

Although I think I'd add a common class to the `block_` elements and select by that class:

```
$(function() {
    $("div.block").hover( function ( e ) {
        $(this).children('.tools').toggle(e.type === 'mouseenter');
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="block" id="block_1">
    <div class="tools" style="display:none;">Tools Here</div>
</div>

<div class="block" id="block_2">
    <div class="tools" style="display:none;">Tools Here</div>
</div>
```

Inside event handlers, the keyword `this` refers to the element that received the event. In this case, the element with the `block_n` ID.

Then you use [the `.children()` method](http://api.jquery.com/children/) to select child element(s) that have the `tools` class.

[The `.toggle()` method](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) can be used to show/hide elements. I've given it an argument that is the result of testing the type of event that took place. If the event was `'mouseenter'`, the `.tools` will be shown, otherwise it will be hidden.

The outer `$(function() {...});` is a shortcut for wrapping your code in [jQuery's `.ready()` method](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), which makes sure that your code doesn't run until the DOM is ready.

You can give [the `.hover()` method](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) two functions if you prefer. Then I'd use the [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) methods instead of `.toggle()`.

```
$(function() {
    $("div[id^=block_]").hover( function () {
        $(this).children('.tools').show();
    }, function () {
        $(this).children('.tools').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: @Frank - You're welcome. I added an edit at the top of this answer giving a pure CSS solution as well. :o)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("*[id^=block_]").hover(function() {
    $(this).children('.tools').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#block_1').mouseover(function(e){
$('#block_2').show();
});
$('#block_1').mouseout(function(e){
$('#block_2').hide();
});
});
```

Here's adding a nice fade effect:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#block_1').mouseover(function(e){
$('#block_2').fadeIn('fast');
});
$('#block_1').mouseout(function(e){
$('#block_2').fadeOut('fast');
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Finaly I found super simple solution for my responsive mega dropdown. This is based on html5 data attribute. Only 3 lines! ;)

```
$('.button, .content').hover(function() {
    $($(this).data('coupling')).toggle();
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QrEuQ/